# Check for specific key values in array - PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to check `$_POST` keys for values

This is $_POST:

```
Array
(
    [user_lastname] => xx
    [user_firstname] => x
    [sex] => x
    [email] => x@email.com
    [key1] => no
    [key2] => yes
    [key3] => no
    [submit] => Next
)
```

These are the keys:

```
$arr = array("key1", "key2", "key3");
```

And was thinking of doing something like this ... just not sure how to go about it.

```
foreach($arr as $ar) {
   //check values $_POST keys for specific value(in my case `yes`)     
}
```

So in the above example, `key2` has a value of `yes`, making it true.

And would like to pop off the `[submit] => Next` key value from `$_POST` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something simple as

```
foreach($arr as $ar) {
   if ($_POST[$ar] == 'yes')
      {
           echo "Key $ar is true";
      }
}
```

Comment: Why? If it isn't set, it isn't 'yes'

Comment: it isnt 'no' also - OP appears to use 'no'/'yes' as strings, not as booleans

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
// loop through your array
foreach ($arr as $ar)
{
// check if the post key exists 
if ( isset($_POST[$ar]) )
{
// it exists, do something, validate it, check its values, etc
}
}
```

As for your last question, just:

```
unset($_POST['submit']);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `in_array` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)) function.

```
if (in_array('email', $arr)) {
    // True, it's in the array.
}
```

Comment: and use array_pop() to remove the last element of the array.